# Point in triangle - SPOJ task

Tags: perl

I am trying to learn Perl by answering some problems from the Polish SPOJ (Sphere Online Judge) site. This is regarding the [*541: Points Within Triangles*](http://pl.spoj.com/problems/T_PINTR/) problem. I will do my best to translate.

I have to find whether a point p=(x,y) is within a triangle defined by its three vertices.

The triangle's coordinates are: p1=(x1; y1), p2=(x2;y2), p3=(x3; y3).
Each of x1,y2,x3 etc. is an integer in the range of (1... 1000).

Each line of input is 8 integers:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x y
 .....
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If all eight values are zero then the program should terminate.

Each line of input should generate a line of output containing single letter:

- **I**, if the point is inside the triangle
- **O**, if the point is outside the triangle
- **E**, if the point is on the triangle

This is my code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

our ($a, @t, $q);
our ($x1, $x2, $x3, $y1, $y2, $y3, $px, $py);
our ($det);
our ($deta, $detb, $detc);

$a = 0;

sub licz {
  ($t[0][0],$t[0][1],$t[1][0],$t[1][1],$t[2][0],$t[2][1])=@_;

  my $ret = (
    $t[0][0]*$t[1][1]+
    $t[1][0]*$t[2][1]+
    $t[2][0]*$t[0][1]-
    $t[2][0]*$t[1][1]-
    $t[0][0]*$t[2][1]-
    $t[1][0]*$t[0][1]
  );

  return ($ret);
}

sub czek {
  $deta = licz($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $px, $py);
  $detb = licz($x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $px, $py);
  $detc = licz($x3, $y3, $x1, $y1, $px, $py);
  if ($deta == 0 or $detb == 0 or $detc == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0
  }
}

sub kier {
  if ($det > 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}

while () {
  my @tab = split(/\s+/, <>);
  if ( $tab[0] and $tab[1] and $tab[2] and $tab[3] and $tab[4] and $tab[5] and $tab[6] and $tab[7] ) {
    $x1  = $tab[0];
    $y1  = $tab[1];
    $x2  = $tab[2];
    $y2  = $tab[3];
    $x3  = $tab[4];
    $y3  = $tab[5];
    $px  = $tab[6];
    $py  = $tab[7];
    $det = licz($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3);

    if (czek()) {
      print("E\n");
    }
    else {
      if (kier()) {
        if ($deta > 0 and $detb > 0 and $detc > 0) {
          print("I\n");
        }
        else {
          print("O\n")
        }
      }
      else {
        if ($deta < 0 and $detb < 0 and $detc < 0) {
          print("I\n")
        }
        else {
          print("O\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    last
  }
}
```

I do not understand why I do not get AC (WA) all the time. All the inputs I have tested have good answers, so I think it's a problem with some spaces or something like that. If anyone can help me, please do.

Comment: Not everything on this line is defined `my $ret=($t[0][0]*$t[1][5]+$t[1][0]*$t[2][6]+$t[2][0]*$t[0][7]-$t[2][0]*$t[1][8]-$t[0][0]*$t[2][9]-$t[1][0]*$t[0][10]);`

Comment: Since items are not defined, you are getting warnings and the result based on the the undefined items is to use zero in multiplying items together, so it will return 0 as you don't have all of the items initialized. I'm not sure to what values they need to be set.

Comment: @user3809977: I have tidied up your question a little. Please roll it back if I have got it wrong. Please explain what you mean by *"I do not get AC (WA) all the time"*. It would also help if you explained your algorithm and the meanings of your subroutines `licz`, `czek`, and `kier`. I'm afraid my vector mechanics is very rusty!

Comment: Does `licz` calculate the determinant of a matrix? It is building a 3×5 array from the parameters and then using it as if it was 3×11

Comment: @Malin: That helps a little. Please answer the questions in my comment above

Comment: Matt somebody made it wrong while editing, now it's okay.
Glenn nope, no warnings from ideone check there: http://ideone.com/DcKl4V
@Borodin AC = Accepted, WA = Wrong Answer, sorry I thoguht that all over the world those acronyms are well known.
licz() is for calculating matrix
in czek() i am calculating 'det' - determinant of matrix a,b,c ( from three vectors to check if point(x,y) is ON the triangle or not. 
kier() checks the 'side' of triangle I mean this : http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~lrybicki/geometria/plusminus.gif

On the end i check if point is on left / right side of vectors

Comment: @Bordin sorry for my sloppiness in english if there is anything i can explain just let me know.

Comment: I ran the script that you have made changes and it seems to be working.  With the numbers provided by the website, I get the expected results based on the information from the website.

Comment: @Glenn exactly! And there is a problem! After hours of thinking and calculating nothing comes to my mind why SPOJ says that I done it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Working algorithm in other answer

I've already demonstrated a working algorithm for this problem in my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24600967/1733163).  However, you're also inquiring as to why your code was not accepted as an answer.

#### An example of where your logic fails

One example of where your code fails for the following data:

```
1 1 4 1 4 4 5 5
```

The point `(5,5)` will be incorrectly reported as on an edge instead of outside the below triangle:

[image: Triangle (1,1);(4,1);(4,4) Point (5,5)]

Basically, any point that is along the vector created by an edge is reported as actually on the edge.   Therefore, the following points will also be reported as on an edge: `(500, 500)`, `(4, -9000)`, `(0,0)`, etc.

To show you were your logic is failing it is necessary to clean up your code.

#### Coding style fixes

Kudos to you for including [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  That is the first step to becoming a good programmer in perl.

However, one next step is to never use global variables for anything but constants.  **Always pass parameters to your subroutines and return values.**  It is of course possible to code in other ways, but keeping each subroutine as an isolated thought or idea helps with readability and maintainability.

Applying this one single coding style reduces your program to the following:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub licz {
    my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3) = @_;
    return ($x1*$y2 - $x2*$y1) + ($x2*$y3 - $x3*$y2) + ($x3*$y1 - $x1*$y3);
}

while (<DATA>) {
    my @tab = split(/\s+/, $_);
    last if grep {!$_} @tab[0..7];

    my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $px, $py) = @tab;

    my $det = licz($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3);
    my $deta = licz($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $px, $py);
    my $detb = licz($x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $px, $py);
    my $detc = licz($x3, $y3, $x1, $y1, $px, $py);

    if ($deta == 0 || $detb == 0 || $detc == 0) {
        print("E\n");
    }
    elsif ($det > 0) {
        if ($deta > 0 and $detb > 0 and $detc > 0) {
            print("I\n");
        }
        else {
            print("O\n")
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($deta < 0 and $detb < 0 and $detc < 0) {
            print("I\n")
        }
        else {
            print("O\n");
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
630 421 326 242 561 432 478 332
378 212 380 550 840 735 379 381
591 916 765 191 487 490 678 554
975 75 324 166 343 28 650 120
1 1 4 1 4 4 500 500
1 1 1 4 4 4 5 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### The Flaw in your logic

Now, as you can see, your program looks very similar to mine in its reduced form.  In fact, we're using the same formula.  Yours is just the reduced form of the vector cross products, where I start with the point subtraction.  The values in your program of `($deta, $detb, $detc)` are equivalent to `($cps[0], $cps[1], $cps[2])` in mine.

These values tell us whether or not a point is to the right, left, or along an edge.  They do this by the sign of the value.  You also calculate the clockwise or counter clockwise nature of the triangle using `$det`.  However, you do not need this information.

Basically, if we go around the 3 edges of a triangle, and a point is to the right of each edge, then the point must be INSIDE the triangle.  Similarly, if we go around the 3 edges, and a point is to the left of each edge, then we can also conclude that the point must be inside the triangle and that we must have traversed the triangle counter clockwise.  In the end, the sign of each of the cross products doesn't matter, only whether the signs all match or not.

- Sign of cross products all match ⇒ Point is inside the triangle
- Both positive and negative signs ⇒ Point is outside the triangle

Now, if the sign of a cross product is Zero, we know that the point is **along an edge**, but that's not enough information to determine if the point is actually **on the edge**.  There are five different cases.  I'll start with the obvious ones:

1. If two cross products are Zero ⇒ Point matches a vertice of the triangle
2. If the non-zero cross products are both positive ⇒ Point is on an edge
3. If the non-zero cross products are both negative ⇒ Point is on an edge
4. If there is both a negative and positive cross product ⇒ Point is along edge but outside.

Now, hopefully this reveals the flaw in your logic.  Basically, you check to see if a cross product is zero, but you don't check the sign of the other cross products.  In fact, one can and should just check to see if a point is outside before bothering to check if it is along an edge, like demonstrated in my solution.

I've now laid out exactly what you need to do to fix your code, but I leave the final edits to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Point Inside or Outside Triangle?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170028/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54505.html) as a guide, the following uses the vector cross product to determine if a point inside, outside, or on the edge of a triangle:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    last if !/[1-9]/;
    #print;
    my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $x, $y) = split;

    my @cps = (
        ($x1 - $x2) * ($y1 - $y) - ($x1 - $x) * ($y1 - $y2),
        ($x2 - $x3) * ($y2 - $y) - ($x2 - $x) * ($y2 - $y3),
        ($x3 - $x1) * ($y3 - $y) - ($x3 - $x) * ($y3 - $y1),
    );

    # Both Negative and Positive Cross Products means is outside
    if (grep {$_ > 0} @cps and grep {$_ < 0} @cps) {
        print "   Outside\n";

    # A Zero Cross Product means is on an edge as long as the sign of all other CP's match
    } elsif (my $zeros = grep {$_ == 0} @cps) {
        print $zeros == 1
            ? "   Edge\n"
            : "   Vertice\n";

    # Same Sign for all CP's means is Inside.
    } else {
        print "   Inside\n";
    }

__DATA__
630 421 326 242 561 432 478 332
378 212 380 550 840 735 379 381
591 916 765 191 487 490 678 554
975 75 324 166 343 28 650 120
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Outputs:

```
   Inside
   Edge
   Outside
   Inside
```

Comment: My problem isn't that my algorithm is bad, problem is 'why SPOJ doesn't accept it.

Comment: @Malin No, your problem is your algorithm.  I've added a new answer that shows you a few data points where your code fails, and attempts to advise you on how to clean up your coding style, and finally point out the flaw in your logic.

Comment: @Miller I added missing closing curly before __DATA__. Then it works.